# load a post into a div

Tags: php, jquery, post

In effect, I want to say this:

```
$('#results1').html($.post("videoloaderurl.php", { id: byName } ));
```

Obviously, the code above doesn't work. 
where results1 is a div and videoloaderurl.php returns html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide `success` callback function for `post` function, which could add retrived data to the div.

```
$.post("videoloaderurl.php", { id: byName }, function(data) {
  $('#results1').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.post()` is an AJAX method - meaning it is Asynchronous. You have to wait for the data to be returned and do something in the callback rather than the function returning the value.

```
$.post("videoloaderurl.php", { id: byName }, function(d){
    $('#results1').html(d)
});
```